# Isotopies in embeddings into $S^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I am refering to [this](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Eandyp/notes/SpanierWhitehead.pdf) document about the Spanier-Whitehead Duality. The setting is that $X$ is a compact simplicial complex and $f,g\colon X \to S^n$ are two simplicial embeddings. In the first sentence of the proof, the author says:

> If $n$ is sufficiently large relative to the dimension of $X$, then $f$ and $g$ are isotopic, so $S^n \backslash f(X)$ is homeomorphic to $S^n \backslash g(X)$.

I have the following questions:

1. From what I understand, a simplicial embedding is an injective function between simplicial complexes such that there is an isomorphism between the $0$-simplices, simplices go to simplices, and a face of a simplex goes to a face of the same simplex. Is this definition correct? And in this case, is any embedding $f\colon X \to S^n$ a simplicial embedding? It does seem so to me, since I think we can create $S^n$ with as many simplices as we like.
2. I can intuitively understand why $f$ and $g$ would be isotopic—there is enough space to 'move' $X$ around in $S^n$ if $n$ is large. Is there some theorem that would make this intuition more concrete?
3. I do not understand why $S^n \backslash f(X)$ is homeomorphic to $S^n \backslash g(X)$.

Comment: Do you know what a wild knot is?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Just looked them up, now I do

Comment: Now you know the answer to 1, right?

Comment: Part 3 is just the matter of knowing the definition of isotopy.

Comment: Part 2: Check the book by Rourke and Sanderson "Introduction to PL topology", chapter 5, it should be there.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I realise the definition of isotopy should be used in Part 3, but I still do not understand how

Comment: Then add the **relevant** (there are several inequivalent ones!) definition of isotopy in your question. It is hard to help you if you do not tell us exactly what are you missing.